# BigQuery How to display Tree view when depth level I found error Resources exceeded during query execution

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, tree, hierarchy

My data is below

| room | object | superia |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | A | AAA |
| 01 | B | BBB |

and My code is below when I type in e4 ..select..bra ba until finish then I found error "Resources exceeded during query execution: Not enough resources for query planning - too many subqueries or query is too complex."

```
WITH e0 AS (
  SELECT room,object AS object ,superia FROM edc_sap.v_eq_fl WHERE 
type_table = 'EQ'
), e1 AS (
  SELECT e.room,e.object,e.superia,t.superia as superia2
  FROM e0 e LEFT JOIN edc_sap.v_eq_fl t ON t.object = e.superia
), e2 AS (
  SELECT e.room,e.object,e.superia, superia2 ,t.superia as superia3
  FROM e1 e LEFT JOIN edc_sap.v_eq_fl t ON t.object = e.superia2 
), e3 AS (
  SELECT e.room,e.object,e.superia, superia2 ,superia3,t.superia as 
    superia4
  FROM e2 e LEFT JOIN edc_sap.v_eq_fl t ON t.object = e.superia3 
) , e4 AS (
  SELECT e.room,e.object,e.superia, superia2 
,superia3,superia4,t.superia as superia5
  FROM e3 e LEFT JOIN edc_sap.v_eq_fl t ON t.object = e.superia4 
) 
SELECT room,superia5,superia4,superia3,superia2,superia,object FROM e4
```

and output I would like to display Superia5,Superia6,..bra ba

| room | superia6 | superia5 | superia4 | superia3 | superia2 | superia | object |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | FFF | EEE | DDD | CCC | BBB | AAA | A |
| 01 | FFF | EEE | DDD | CCC | BBB | AAA | B |

Comment: have you tried wrapping your query inside a procedure? I had a very large query that was giving me the same error and wrapping it inside a procedure worked for me.

Comment: @Shogun187 I tried to create procedure and add OPTIONS(strict_mode=false) for not to cause an error when I call procedure that have same error message

Comment: I change WITH ..as to left join table I think it work @Shogun187 Thank you